# "Where should Jack go?" - a GCHQ word association puzzle

Tags: knowledge, wordplay, pattern, connect-wall

Inspired by Stiv's fantastic [Where? word association puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/110394/introducing-where-a-gchq-word-association-puzzle), I decided to create my own. Special thanks to [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644/stiv) for test-solving and general feedback!

**Instructions** (adapted from [The GCHQ Puzzle Book (2016)](https://www.gchq.gov.uk/news/gchq-challenges-you-crack-codes-charity-launch-its-first-ever-puzzle-book) and [Stiv's original puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/110394/introducing-where-a-gchq-word-association-puzzle)): The words in the following list can be partitioned into equal-sized sets depending on words associated with them; each set has its own word association method. This list is arranged so that *these associated words are in alphabetical order*. One of these sets is missing a member, so you have to work out where in the list the associated word fits alphabetically, and hence where the word itself should appear in the list. The list should be read from left to right and top to bottom and is only written in columns for convenience. See [the original puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/110394/introducing-where-a-gchq-word-association-puzzle) for a more detailed explanation and an example.

---

Now, without further ado...

> **Where does ‘Jack’ fit in the following list?**

|  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Malice | Java | Emily | Free | Ladder |
| One | Rain | Physics | Ice | Club |
| Ragged | Drat | Martha | King | Chop |
| Hound | Lemma | Captain | Hero | Land |
| Growled | Germany | Air | Sharper | Dark |
| Arrest | Duck | Hands | Donkey | Clean |
| Rock | Came | Detector | Dance | Ten |
| Bolivia | Piranha | Quiz | Knowledge | White |
| Repair | Friends | Groomsmen | Arguably | Truth |
| Baby | Reaps | Pine | Life | Strains |
| Steerable | High | Pokémon | Rwanda | Baba |

*As with Stiv's puzzle, please hold off posting partial answers unless you think you have found at least half of the correct word associations (although if you make it that far, why not push to complete the whole puzzle!). Hope you enjoy!*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Jack should go

> between Detector and Dance.

The groups are

> **Women's names by removing first letter:** (m)Alice, (j)Ava, (l)Emma, (s)Harper, (b)Olivia, (t)Ruth, (r)Wanda
>
>  **"x is y", video game names:** (Emily is) Away, (Martha is) Dead, (Chop is) Dish, (Knowledge is) Power, (Life is) Strange, (Baba is) You
>
>  **Song titles with animal names:** (Free) Bird, (Hound) Dog, (Dark) Horse, (Rock) Lobster, (Dance) Monkey, (White) Rabbit, (Baby) Shark
>
>  **Body parts with first letter missing:** B-ladder, B-one, B-rain, G-land, H-air, S-pine, T-high
>
>  **Compound nouns where the first word is a style of music:** Classical (Physics), Country (Club), Folk (Hero), House (Arrest), Jazz (Hands), Metal (Detector), Pop (Quiz)
>
>  **Playable characters in the Super Smash Bros video game:** (Ice) Climbers, (King) Dedede, (Captain) Falcon, (Duck) Hunt, (Donkey) Kong, (Piranha) Plant, (Pokémon) Trainer
>
>  **Anagrams of weapons:** Dagger (Ragged), Dart (Drat), Lance (Clean), Mace (Came), Net (Ten), Rapier (Repair), Spear (Reaps)
>
>  **Colours when taking every other letter:** G(r)o(w)l(e)d, G(e)r(m)a(n)y, (f)R(i)e(n)d(s), (g)R(o)o(m)s(m)e(n), (a)R(g)u(a)b(l)y, (s)T(r)a(i)n(s), (s)T(e)e(r)a(b)l(e)
>
>  All of these groups are additionally hinted by having some additional group members in the original list (E.g., names: Emily, games: Pokémon, animals: Duck, body parts: Hands, music: Rock, ssb character: Hero, weapon: Club, colour: White)
>
>  A full list of the words is given in the picture below
>  [image]

The missing member is

> in the video game group, for which we can find the suitable solution **Jack is missing**.

Comment: Fantastic solution! I usually wait a day before accepting, but a green check's coming your way :D