# "Guess Where?" - a GCHQ word association puzzle (board game edition)

Tags: knowledge, wordplay, pattern, connect-wall, board-games

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #7: Board games](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7441/monthly-topic-challenge-7-board-games?cb=1).</sub>

---

**Instructions** (adapted from [The GCHQ Puzzle Book (2016)](https://www.gchq.gov.uk/news/gchq-challenges-you-crack-codes-charity-launch-its-first-ever-puzzle-book) and [the introductory puzzle here on Puzzling Stack Exchange](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/110394/introducing-where-a-gchq-word-association-puzzle)): The words in the following list can be **partitioned into equal-sized sets** depending on words associated with them; each set has its own word association method. This list is arranged so that *these associated words are in alphabetical order*. **One of these sets is missing a member**, so you have to work out where in the list the associated word fits alphabetically, and hence where the word itself should appear in the list. The list should be read from left to right and top to bottom and is only written in columns for convenience. (See [the introductory puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/110394/introducing-where-a-gchq-word-association-puzzle) for a more detailed explanation and an example.)

---

The question to answer is:

> **Where does 'NUMBER' fit in the following list?**

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| APPLE | CENTRAL | WESTERN | ILL | SLEEVE | GEO | FLOP |
| FREEZE | BASKET | TRICK | GREAT | ART | SKIPPER | HORSE |
| RECHECKS | CHEST | AVID | MIDDLE | COMPANY | STANDARD | VAGUE |
| TRAIN | SCENE | NEW | JAIL | TAX | PRAWN | RIDER |
| FILE | LOUD | ALMANAC | ARIA | DIGGER | CLUSTERED | SPORT |
| IRE | SHOP | ENTER | SOME | BEE | AM | CHARLOTTE |
| OM | WITTERS | WORKS | FLIGHT | FOOL | CRAMP | HIS |

Crucially this time, **every set relates to board games** in some way.

*In the first instance, please hold off posting partial answers unless you think you have found at least half of the correct word associations (although if you make it that far, why not push to complete the whole puzzle!). Thank you, and enjoy!*

Comment: By any chance, are NEW and JAIL the wrong way round?

Comment: @hexomino Nope :) Thanks for checking though - it's very easy to make a mistake when setting these up! Sounds like one of your set members might not be quite right...

Comment: Thanks, the JAIL is probably wrong so I might need something else to fit in that category.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Categories:

> 1. Second word of *Operation* piece, take first word
>  2. First word of *Risk* region, take second word
>  3. *Guess Who* character with first letter removed, take original name
>  4. Second word of phrase whose first word is a *chess* piece, take chess piece
>  5. First few letters of *Trivial Pursuit* category, take category color
>  6. Synonym of *Stratego* piece, take original piece
>  7. *Settlers of Catan* resource with first letter changed, take original resource
>  8. Anagram of the *name of a board game*, take original name of game
>  9. Second word of *Monopoly* space, take first word
>  10. Word that rhymes with last name of *Clue* character, take original name

Matchings:

> APPLE - ADAM’S - Operation
>  CENTRAL - AMERICA - Risk
>  WESTERN - AUSTRALIA - Risk
>  ILL - BILL - Guess Who
>  SLEEVE - BISHOP - Chess
>  GEO - BLUE - Trivial Pursuit
>  FLOP - BOMB - Stratego
>  FREEZE - BRAIN - Operation
>  BASKET - BREAD - Operation
>  TRICK - BRICK - Catan
>  GREAT - BRITAIN - Risk
>  ART - BROWN - Trivial Pursuit
>  SKIPPER - CAPTAIN - Stratego
>  HORSE - CHARLIE - Operation
>  RECHECKS - CHECKERS - Anagram
>  CHEST - COMMUNITY - Monopoly
>  AVID - DAVID - Guess Who
>  MIDDLE - EAST - Risk
>  COMPANY - ELECTRIC - Monopoly
>  STANDARD - FLAG - Stratego
>  VAGUE - GENERAL - Stratego
>  TRAIN - GRAIN - Catan
>  SCENE - GREEN - Clue
>  NEW - GUINEA - Risk
>  JAIL - IN - Monopoly
>  TAX - INCOME - Monopoly
>  PRAWN - KING - Chess
>  RIDER - KNIGHT - Chess
>  FILE - LIFE - Anagram
>  LOUD - LUDO - Anagram
>  **NUMBER - LUMBER - Catan**
>  ALMANAC - MANCALA - Anagram
>  ARIA - MARIA - Guess Who
>  DIGGER - MINER - Stratego
>  CLUSTERED - MUSTARD - Clue
>  SPORT - ORANGE - Trivial Pursuit
>  IRE - ORE - Catan
>  SHOP - PAWN - Chess
>  ENTER - PINK - Trivial Pursuit
>  SOME - PLUM - Clue
>  BEE - QUEEN - Chess
>  AM - SAM - Guess Who
>  CHARLOTTE - SCARLET - Clue
>  OM - TOM - Guess Who
>  WITTERS - TWISTER - Anagram
>  WORKS - WATER - Monopoly
>  FLIGHT - WHITE - Clue
>  FOOL - WOOL - Catan
>  CRAMP - WRITER’S - Operation
>  HIS - YELLOW - Trivial Pursuit

Comment: Well done! I was still missing two categories.

Comment:  well done, that's a lot of figuring out, and in only a few hours!

Comment: All correct - nice work! Checkmark awarded... :)