# "Where does sushi go?" - a GCHQ word association puzzle (anime edition)

Tags: knowledge, wordplay, pattern, connect-wall, anime

<sub>*No, the title does not refer to the card game Sushi Go; if you're looking for board games, check out [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644/stiv)'s ["Guess Where?"](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119926/guess-where-a-gchq-word-association-puzzle-board-game-edition?rq=1) puzzle! ;)*</sub>

---

**Instructions** (adapted from [The GCHQ Puzzle Book (2016)](https://www.gchq.gov.uk/news/gchq-challenges-you-crack-codes-charity-launch-its-first-ever-puzzle-book) and [the introductory puzzle here on Puzzling Stack Exchange](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/110394/introducing-where-a-gchq-word-association-puzzle)): The words in the following list can be **partitioned into equal-sized sets** depending on words associated with them; each set has its own word association method. This list is arranged so that *these associated words are in alphabetical order*. **One of these sets is missing a member**, so you have to work out where in the list the associated word fits alphabetically, and hence where the word itself should appear in the list. The list should be read from left to right and top to bottom and is only written in columns for convenience. (See [the introductory puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/110394/introducing-where-a-gchq-word-association-puzzle) for a more detailed explanation and an example.)

---

The question to answer is:

> **Where does 'Sushi' go in the following list?**

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Beach | Shield | Ark | Green | Wren | Airy | Foo |
| Ire | Lying | Frog | Host | Spice | Ton | Round |
| Stone | Serpent | Engine | Pearl | Sky | Insect | Fight |
| War | Trade | Rabbit | Job | Donkey | Sea | Acid |
| Black | Time | Wind | Homing | Mist | Water | Love |

Crucially this time, **every set relates to anime** in some way.

*Please hold off posting partial answers unless you think you have found at least half of the correct word associations (although if you make it that far, why not push to complete the whole puzzle!). Thank you, and enjoy!*

## Hints

1. > A couple of categories require some knowledge not exclusive to anime that is well-known or easy to find.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

List:

> [image: Table]

Groups:

> **A**: Rock bands, and also the [Stands](https://jojowiki.com/List_of_Stands) in JoJo's Bizarre Adventure series
>
> • Beach **BOY**
>
> • Green **DAY**
>
> • Foo **FIGHTERS**
>
> • Spice **GIRL**
>
> • Pearl **JAM**
>
> • Black **SABBATH**
>
>
> **B**: [Quirk](https://myheroacademia.fandom.com/wiki/Quirk) users in My Hero Academia series, with their aliases("Hero name")
>
> • Shield: **CRUST**
>
> • Frog: **FROPPY** (Tsuyu Asui)
>
> • Engine: **INGENIUM** (Tenya Ida)
>
> • Rabbit: **MIRKO** (Rumi Usagiyama)
>
> • Acid: **PINKY** (Mina Ashido)
>
> • Homing: **SNIPE**
>
>
> **C**: Pokémon types, by adding first letters
>
> • **[D]ARK**
>
> • **[F]AIRY**
>
> • **[F]IRE**
>
> • **[F]LYING**
>
> • **[G]HOST**
>
> • **[G]ROUND**
>
>
> **D**: [Hashira](https://kimetsu-no-yaiba.fandom.com/wiki/Hashira) members in Demon Slayer: Kimetsu no Yaiba series
>
> • Stone: Gyomei **HIMEJIMA**
>
> • Serpent: Obanai **IGURO**
>
> • Insect: Shinobu **KOCHO**
>
> • Wind: Sanemi **SHINAZUGAWA**
>
> • Mist: Muichiro **TOKITO**
>
> • Water: Giyu **TOMIOKA**
>
>
> **E**: Roman deities, and also [Sailor Guardians](https://sailormoon.fandom.com/wiki/Sailor_Guardians#Sailor_Guardians_of_the_Solar_System) in Sailor Moon series
>
> • **JUPITER**: God of sky
>
> • **MARS**: God of war
>
> • **MERCURY**: God of trade
>
> • **NEPTUNE**: God of sea
>
> • **SATURN**: God of time
>
> • **VENUS**: God of love
>
>
> And finally, **X**: Protagonists in famous [shōnen animes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sh%C5%8Dnen_manga), by changing first letters
>
> • **[w→E]REN** Yeager: Attack on Titan
>
> • **[t→G]ON** Freecss: Hunter × Hunter
>
> • **[f→L]IGHT** Yagami: Death Note
>
> • **[j→M]OB** (Shigeo Kageyama): Mob Psycho 100
>
> • **[d→M]ONKEY** D. Luffy: One Piece
>
> • And... **[s→?]USHI**

So, where does 'Sushi' go?

> In my best guess, the word you've lost is **[FUSHI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fushi_(To_Your_Eternity))**, the protagonist of To Your Eternity. I think this anime is less well known than other members, but I couldn't find more suitable one.
>
>
> So, 'Sushi' will go between 'Frog' and 'Host'.

Comment: Yup! What a great first answer! I agree that the corresponding item for "sushi" was more obscure, but I loved the thematic-ness of "sushi" (plus the Sushi Go pun) and the fact that it had its own Wikipedia page made me think it would be OK 