# "Where? Or is it When?!" - a GCHQ word association puzzle

Tags: knowledge, pattern, seasonal, connect-wall, humor

**Instructions** (adapted from [The GCHQ Puzzle Book (2016)](https://www.gchq.gov.uk/news/gchq-challenges-you-crack-codes-charity-launch-its-first-ever-puzzle-book) and [the introductory puzzle here on Puzzling Stack Exchange](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/110394/introducing-where-a-gchq-word-association-puzzle)): The words in the following list can be **partitioned into equal-sized sets** depending on words associated with them; each set has its own word association method. This list is arranged so that *these associated words are in alphabetical order*. **One of these sets is missing a member**, so you have to work out where in the list the associated word fits alphabetically, and hence where the word itself should appear in the list. The list should be read from left to right and top to bottom and is only written in columns for convenience. (See [the introductory puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/110394/introducing-where-a-gchq-word-association-puzzle) for a more detailed explanation and an example.)

---

The question to answer is:

> **Where does 'FOOL' fit in the following list?**

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| O'NEIL | UPRISING | IVY | STEWART | WINE | LAWS | ASHLEY |
| SNOW | SHOWERS | KEPNER | HUNTER | LADY | HEINRICHS | ROSS |
| LOVE | REVOLUTION | MENDEZ | MORNING | GLASPIE | RYAN | STORY |
| SKIES | WINCHELL | CRISIS | THESES | BOWLBY | TWILIGHTS | LUDGATE |

Answer (score 10, accepted):

FOOL would fit

> anywhere in the list!

> There is only 1 set consisting of all of the 28 words. All words can be completed by adding april in front of it. The biggest hint for this is that with FOOL the total number of words would be 29, so either there has to be one big set or 29 sets with 1 word.

And for completeness:

> [April O'Neil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_O%27Neil)
>  [April Uprising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_Uprising_of_1876)
>  [April Ivy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_Ivy)
>  [April Stewart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_Stewart)
>  [April Wine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_Wine)
>  [April Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_Laws)
>  [April Ashley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_Ashley)
>  [April Snow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_Snow)
>  [April Showers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_Showers_(song))
>  [April Kepner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_Kepner)
>  [April Hunter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_Hunter)
>  [April Lady](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_Lady)
>  [April Heinrichs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_Heinrichs)
>  [April Ross](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_Ross)
>  [April Love](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_Love_(painting))
>  [April Revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_Revolution)
>  [April Mendez](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJ_Lee)
>  [April Morning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_Morning)
>  [April Glaspie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_Glaspie)
>  [April Ryan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_Ryan)
>  [April Story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_Story)
>  [April Skies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_Skies)
>  [April Winchell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_Winchell)
>  [April Crisis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_Crisis)
>  [April Theses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_Theses)
>  [April Bowlby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_Bowlby)
>  [April Twilights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_Twilights)
>  [April Ludgate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_Ludgate)
>  [April Fool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_Fool)

Comment: Well worked out :) The number of words was indeed a deliberate clue... I'd love to see some links to relevant Wiki pages to explain the connections, but when I get back from travels and end up at a computer again I can always edit some in myself :)